# Object destruction in Qt dialog

Tags: c++, object-oriented, qt

I am new to Qt and am trying to understand object destruction and where I need to explicitly destroy objects using `delete`.

```
class MainDialog: public QWidget {
        Q_OBJECT
    public: MainDialog(QWidget *parent=0);
    private:
        QPushButton *m_newClick;
          QPushButton *m_editClick;
         MainContact *m_contact;
    }

MainDialog::MainDialog(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent) {
    QWidget *container= new QWidget();

    QPushButton *m_newClick =new QPushButton("New", container);
    QPushButton *m_editClick= new QPushButton("Edit", container);

    QLineEdit *m_text=new QLineEdit(container);

    QVBoxLayout *vlayout=new QVBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout=new QHBoxLayout();
    hlayout->addWidget(m_newClick);
    hlayout->addWidget(m_editClick);
    vlayout->addLayout(hlayout);


    connect(m_viewClick,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(viewClick()) );
    connect(m_newClick,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(newClick()) );

    setWindowTitle("Welcome");

    setLayout(vlayout);

}
```

My queries:

1. Will the `Pushbuttons` and `lineEdits` get destroyed once `container` is destroyed?
2. Do I need to destroy `m_contact` separately as it is not part of the container?

I would like a small explanation on the parent child object destruction as well.

Comment: Your code is "suspicious" in that you're shadowing member variables in the constructor, and have something that's named like a member but isn't (`m_text`). If this is the result of trimming down your code to post here, please correct these aspects - devil's in the details, you don't want people to be reviewing something that's not your actual code.

Answer (score 4):

I see a number of issues with your code, but let me answer your questions first:

**1. Will the Pushbuttons and lineEdits get destroyed once 'container' is destroyed?**

Yes, the pushbuttons and lineedits get destroyed when `container` gets destroyed

**2. Do I need to destroy `m_contact` separately?**

I do not see where `m_contact` is created. In the above code you just declare a pointer to a `MainContact` object. Nothing is created/allocated, so nothing needs to be destroyed.

Recommended reading is the [detailed description of the QObject documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details):

> `QObjects` organize themselves in object trees. When you create a `QObject` with another object as parent, the object will automatically add itself to the parent's `children()` list. The parent takes ownership of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its destructor.

---

I have the impression that you do not have a clear idea what you need to do with all the pointers/objects etc. If my further comments sound like spoonfeeding, then I'm sorry for this. But I think a step-by-step discussion of your code will help you (my comments always *after* the code):

```
class MainDialog: public QWidget {
```

here you declare your class as a subclass of QWidget. this means your class will be a QWidget and therefore a QObject too.

```
        Q_OBJECT
    public: MainDialog(QWidget *parent=0);
    private:
        QPushButton *m_newClick;
          QPushButton *m_editClick;
         MainContact *m_contact;
```

you declare three pointers. No object will be *created* by this. This is just your handle to have access to the objects later.

```
    }

MainDialog::MainDialog(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent) {
```

with `QWidget(parent)` you initialize the `QWidget` component of your class `MainDialog`

```
    QWidget *container= new QWidget();
```

here you create a local pointer to a QWidget and create a new QWidget object without specifying a parent of this new object. *Local* means that this variable is only valid within the scope of this function. To be exact: the scope is between the curly brackets `{}`. The variable will be destroyed when the program flow leaves the scope.

```
    QPushButton *m_newClick =new QPushButton("New", container);
    QPushButton *m_editClick= new QPushButton("Edit", container);
```

here you create two new local pointers to QPushButton objects which (**!!!**) *hiding* the pointers that you have created as private members of your class. Not all compilers will warn you about this. Your code should be just this: `m_newClick =new QPushButton("New", container);`

```
    QLineEdit *m_text=new QLineEdit(container);
```

as above `m_text` is a local pointer and will point to a newly created `QLineEdit` object.

```
    QVBoxLayout *vlayout=new QVBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout=new QHBoxLayout();
    hlayout->addWidget(m_newClick);
    hlayout->addWidget(m_editClick);
    vlayout->addLayout(hlayout);
```

This bit is correct. You are using local pointers to the layouts which is absolutely fine; you don't need them later on. One important point here: the ownership is transferred to the layout. That means, the `container` object is no longer parent of the pushbuttons.

You could avoid the use of local varables by writing it like this: `hlayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("New"));` but then you have no handle to connect with.

```
    connect(m_viewClick,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(viewClick()) );
```

the variable `m_viewClick` is not defined. This is probably just a typo here on [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). But the slot `viewClick()` is also not defined in the class above.

```
    connect(m_newClick,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(newClick()) );
```

same here: `newClick()` is not defined.

```
    setWindowTitle("Welcome");

    setLayout(vlayout);
```

here you set the layout that contains your previously constructed objects to this MainDialog object. `MainDialog` becomes the new *owner* of `vlayout` and with it all the pushbuttons and lineedits.

Perhaps you also need to call `show()`.

```
}
```

here we are at the end of the scope of `MainDialog` constructor function. At this point the following variables will be destroyed: `container` `m_newClick` `m_editClick` `m_text` `vlayout` `hlayout`. These are just the pointers. Since the ownership of all the objects has been transferred, no object will be destroyed. This results in a "leak" of the `container` and `m_text` object.

**Summary of the problems:**

- the container object is useless
- the three private variables `m_newClick` `m_editClick` and `m_contact` are not used.
- the local variables `m_newClick` and `m_editClick` hide private member variables. This is a perfect example why [prefixes on member variables are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228161/why-use-prefixes-on-member-variables-in-c-classes).
- don't connect non-existing functions.

---

**The following is an example with the above suggestions implemented:**

```
class MainDialog : public QWidget 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public: MainDialog(QWidget *parent=0);
public slots:
    void newClick();
    void editClick();
    void endEdit();
}

MainDialog::MainDialog(QWidget *parent)
    :   QWidget(parent) 
{
    QVBoxLayout * vlayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout * hlayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QPushButton * newButton = new QPushButton("New");
    QPushButton * editButton = new QPushButton("Edit");
    QLineEdit * lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
    hlayout->addWidget(newButton);
    hlayout->addWidget(editButton);
    vlayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
    vlayout->addLayout(hlayout);

    connect(editButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(editClick()) );
    connect(newButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(newClick()) );
    connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(editingFinished(), this, SLOT(endEdit()) );

    setWindowTitle("Welcome");    
    setLayout(vlayout);
    show();
}
```